# What is the carrier frequency of Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet

What is the carrier frequency of gigabit Ethernet (1000baseT)?

Apparently this is a full-duplex 4D-PAM5 communication scheme at 125 Mbaud. That is, a carrier signal (a train of pulses) is sent over each twisted pair of conductors (four independent pairs in total), with (5 voltage level) amplitude modulation, meaning the *envelope* discretely changes amplitude every 8 nanoseconds. How often are the pulses?

Comment: there is no carrier per se ... the voltage level does change, but it is not an envelope

Comment: @jsotola why do they call it "pulse amplitude modulation" if there are no carrier pulses, just voltage steps at the baud rate?

Comment: They are using the term modulation in a more generic way than used in radio communication, as in amplitude modulation, or frequency modulation.

Comment: And I think it's "phase amplitude modulation", not "pulse".

Comment: @SteveSh [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-amplitude_modulation#Ethernet) definitely has "pulse" rather than "phase". What would phase refer to here?

Comment: Each level change can be though of as a pulse. Note that because of the encoding, it will never be the case that a long sequence of same level can occur. Transitions are guaranteed. This allows the baud rate to be recovered by the receiver.

Comment: @benjimin yeah the term "pulse amplitude 'modulation'" could certainly lead you to think that a carrier signal was being modulated, but strictly speaking the term means any scheme that puts information into the amplitude of the pulse, regardless of whether it's baseband or modulated onto some carrier signal. In other words "just voltage steps at the baud rate" *does mean* "pulse amplitude modulation" by definition. (This is how the communication systems textbooks define it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no underlying carrier wave. The term *pulse amplitude modulation* here refers to direct modulation of the transmission line voltage.

This is also termed *baseband* transmission (or *line coding*) hence the "base" in 100**BASE**-T.

Presumably line coding increases the complexity of receiver synchronisation, with the trade-off of less demand on the frequency-response of the conduit. 100baseT does utilise extra redundancy in its coding scheme (that at any point transmits only 4 out of 5 possible levels) in a way that assists clock recovery.

Comment: Nothing but comments for 5 hours, then multiple detailed answers posted within 10 minutes after wikifying some insights from those comments!

Comment: This is the most direct answer to the question posed. Ehernet does not use a carrier, and so asking about the frequency of the carrier really doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

As jsotola said in the comments there is no carrier frequency.

Having a carrier frequency means that your baseband data signal is modulated onto some other carrier (for example a radio frequency carrier or a certain wavelength of light), and then it gets demodulated back to baseband at the receiver. That doesn't happen with 1000BaseT Ethernet.

If you're really wondering *what does the frequency content of a 1000baseT Ethernet signal look like*, that's a more interesting question. Like many interesting questions, it's not too hard to give a general sense of the answer but to get a fully detailed accurate answer... well that rabbit hole goes very deep.

For a pulse train of data, the frequency spectrum generally looks like this image excerpted from this [EETimes Article "Spectral content of NRZ test patterns"](https://m.eet.com/media/1134689/15451-447007.pdf), which is a good resource to read in general.

[image]

- The envelope of the spectrum is shaped as a sinc-squared function, i.e. it follows the curve \$\left({\sin(x)\over x}\right)^2\$ where \$x\$ is proportional to frequency.
- Inside this envelope we have a bunch of "grass". For a periodic signal (for example if the pulses had a repeating pattern of `00110011` then this "grass" would consist of a small number of thin spectral lines. (The linked article has some nice examples of these.) For very random data the "grass" pretty much fills up the entire area, as you see in the picture above.
- The first null (the first point where the envelope goes to zero) occurs at 1x the pulse rate. In the picture above this is 2.5GHz for a 2.5Gbps signal. For 1000BaseT we have a 125MHz signaling rate so this null will occur at 125MHz.
- After that first null there isn't too much meaningful signal power and the frequencies are high enough to cause problems, so oftentimes people take measures to filter that out and the final spectrum looks a bit different.

As others have noted, 1000BaseT also employs randomization to assist in clock recovery. Also, there are other tricks to allow for error detection and correction as well as control symbols. For more than you ever wanted to know about the subject, see [the tutorial "Gigabit Ethernet 1000BaseT Physical Coding Sublayer (PCS) Functional Basics and Overview"](https://www.iol.unh.edu/sites/default/files/knowledgebase/ge/pcs.pdf).

Comment: That 100baseT tutorial presentation has excellent detail!